# Android date/time displaying 0 instead of 12

Tags: android, date, time

I wonder what's wrong with my code below:

```
 // Assign hour set in the picker
        c.set( Calendar.HOUR, selectedHour );
        c.set( Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute );

        // For alternative times
        c.add( Calendar.HOUR, SUB_SIX_HOUR );
        c.add( Calendar.MINUTE, SUB_FLAT_MINUTE );

        hour = c.get( Calendar.HOUR );
        minute = c.get( Calendar.MINUTE );
        hour = c.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY );

        StringBuilder sb4 = new StringBuilder();
        if(hour>=12){                      
          sb4.append(hour-12).append( ":" ).append(minute).append(" PM");
        }else if(hour == 0){
          sb4.append( "12" ).append( ":" ).append(minute).append( "AM" );
        }else{
          sb4.append(hour).append( ":" ).append(minute).append(" AM");
        }


        alternative.setText( "Alternative times: " + sb3 + " (9 hours)" + sb4 + " (6 hours)" );
```

Please help me figure out how to display 12 instead of 0 when the calculated time is 12:00 midnight. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 hour = c.get( Calendar.HOUR );
 minute = c.get( Calendar.MINUTE );
 hour = c.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY );
```

You are setting `hour` again after it was already set.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, I set it for AM/PM

Comment: @absk hey question once again, when I click 12:00 Pm it displays 0:00 PM, how to change it to 12:00 PM? thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use this to check for AM or PM.

```
c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
```

See here for documentation [Calendar.AM_PM](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#AM_PM)