# Android time 0:00 pm should be displaying 12:00 pm instead

Tags: java, android, date, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android date/time displaying 0 instead of 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13891427/android-date-time-displaying-0-instead-of-12)

Below is the code I use:

```
public void onTimeSet( TimePicker view, int selectedHour,
            int selectedMinute ) {
        // Gets current time
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

        hour = selectedHour;
        minute = selectedMinute;

        // set waking time into textview
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if( hour >= 12 ){                      
          sb.append(hour-12).append( ":" ).append(pad(minute)).append(" PM");
        }else if( hour == 0 ){
            sb.append( "12" ).append( ":" ).append( pad(minute) ).append( " AM" );
        } else if( hour == 24 ){
            sb.append(hour+24).append( ":" ).append( pad(minute) ).append( " PM" );
        }

        else{
          sb.append(hour).append( ":" ).append(pad(minute)).append(" AM");
        }

        // Assign hour set in the picker
        c.set( Calendar.HOUR, selectedHour );
        c.set( Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute );

        // Have Calendar calculate the substraction of hours and minutes
        c.add( Calendar.HOUR, SUB_HOUR );
        c.add( Calendar.MINUTE, SUB_MINUTE );

        // Get the hour and the minute calculated
        hour = c.get( Calendar.HOUR );
        minute = c.get( Calendar.MINUTE );
        //hour = c.get( Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY );

        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        if(hour>=12){                      
          sb2.append(hour-12).append( ":" ).append(pad(minute)).append(" PM");
        }else if(hour == 0){
          sb2.append( "12" ).append( ":" ).append(pad(minute)).append( " AM" );
        }
        else{
          sb2.append(hour).append( ":" ).append(pad(minute)).append(" AM");
        }

        // set current time into textview
        answer.setText( "To wake up at " + sb + ", you must go to bed at " + sb2 );
```

In my first **StringBuilder**, when the user would choose 12:00 pm, it's displaying in 0:00 Pm not 12:00 pm, how can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you are upto? displaying 24 hour time into 12 hour or something else?

Comment: displaying 24 hour into 12 hr

Comment: `%12` and `if(hour == 0) hour = 12;`

Comment: @anthropomo what do u mean by %12? thanks

Comment: That's modulus 12. Gives the remainer of x/12. So 23 % 12 = 11. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The suggested duplicate doesn't really answer the question. Before string building, you need the following

```
hour = hour % 12
if(hour == 0)
    hour = 12;
```

__

Update:
Before the modulus, do this:

```
// set this variable so it will be in scope

boolean morning = true
//then
if (hour >=12 && hour <  24) morning = false;
else morning = true;
```

And use that boolean value in your stringbuilder

Comment: Hi I tried your code, but when I click the PM button, it's displaying 12:00 AM?

Comment: Still getting the same error. But now it's strange, I chose 12:00 AM it's not displaying in AM